# Netbeans 7.0.1 acts weird, couldn't even edit the GUI in design mode

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, netbeans, netbeans7.0

I'm experiencing a very weird problem in **Netbeans 7.0.1** while designing a GUI.
At first it was all good, I could design and adjust all the swing components easily and normally. But today, for any reason, it turned to be faulty in which the whole `JFrame` is extended vertically way way way down (~37,000 in height!), and all the components mixed up messily. However, I couldn't do anything about this, since this happened it doesn't allow me to drag the frame's bottom side upward to minimize the height.
The worst thing is that I couldn't select (click on) some of the components, but some others can be. I don't know how to thoroughly explain this weird thing, just have a look at the Screen shot. [image]

Tell me if you need any further info.
Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Select the JFrame component from the Navigator panel, and change the height of the JFrame from the properties panel to something like 200.  Once you get the size under control, you can use mouse for resizing it to desired size.

This condition may happen if something went wrong while closing the file or if the IDE was terminated abruptly and if the IDE does not get a chance to write all the metadata about the UI properly.

Answer (score 0):

First Note that You can't resize the JFrame if one of the components is the same length as th JFrame. Try resizing that tabbed pane first, then also the list on the left of the tabbed pane (Ongoing Projects).

Next use the inspector to select any component you couldn't select. It might be that another transparent component is covering it, or that it is in a panel and the panel is getting selected instead. Or even the other way round when you can't select a panel because it contains another component. So use the inspector to select components instead.

Finally, if the scroll bar is too long for you to resize easily, you can use the properties window, but note like I said, resize the components in the JFrame first before resizing the JFrame.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the size (Height and width) of frame in preferredSize property,and use Panels. Without panels you cannot achieve the arrangement of different objects on a Frame.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of frustration over multiple failed attempts at fixing this issue using all the tips given by the users above [thanks everyone, but it didn't work :(   ], I restarted the NetBeans application in despair. It worked. Hopefully this'll help someone else with the same problem!